# Foundation 4 Orbit Slider All Images at Once/Not Scrollable

Tags: html, sass, zurb-foundation, orbit

I can't figure out why the slider doesn't perform exactly like the one on the documentation page here:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html

Our site is
[here:](http://foundationtest.tx0rx0.com/tx0rx0/testpage.html)

Here's the code. I think that it is supposed to be this minimal markup and that the rest of the stuff is supposed to be added later:

```
      <ul data-orbit>
  <li>
    <img src="img/sliders/lightcubebeta1000.png" >
    <div class="orbit-caption">...</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="img/sliders/hammertime1000.png">
    <div class="orbit-caption">...</div>
  </li>
  <li>
   <img src= "img/sliders/alarmclockbeta1000.png">
    <div class="orbit-caption">...</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Initialization of the Javascript:

```
 <!-- Javascript for Orbit Image Slider -->     
<script>
        document.write('<script src=`javascripts/vendor/'
            + ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery')
            + '.js><\/script>')
</script>

<script src= "javascripts/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src= "javascripts/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>
<script src= "javascripts/foundation/foundation.section.js"></script>
<script src= "javascripts/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
<script src= "javascripts/foundation/foundation.orbit.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Foundation -->

<script>

    $(document).foundation('orbit', {
  timer_speed: 10000,
  pause_on_hover: true,
  resume_on_mouseout: true,
  animation_speed: 500,
  bullets: true,
  stack_on_small: true,
  container_class: 'orbit-container',
  stack_on_small_class: 'orbit-stack-on-small',
  next_class: 'orbit-next',
  prev_class: 'orbit-prev',
  timer_container_class: 'orbit-timer',
  timer_paused_class: 'paused',
  timer_progress_class: 'orbit-progress',
  slides_container_class: 'orbit-slides-container',
  bullets_container_class: 'orbit-bullets',
  bullets_active_class: 'active',
  slide_number_class: 'orbit-slide-number',
  caption_class: 'orbit-caption',
  active_slide_class: 'active',
  orbit_transition_class: 'orbit-transitioning'
});

</script>
```

Despite my best efforts to copy the example on the docs page, the orbit image slider displays all the images at once top to bottom with the bullets and the arrows. Did I make a mistake or is there something wrong with the example in the foundation 4 docs?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you lolmaus. It turned out that after changing the `<ul class="data-orbit">` back to <`ul data-orbit>` and by changing:

```
<script>
  document.write('<script src=/js/vendor/'
    + ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery')
    + '.js><\/script>');
</script>
```

to

```
<script>
        document.write('<script src=`javascripts/vendor/'
            + ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery')
            + '.js><\/script>')
</script>
```

It then appears to load zepto or jquery correctly, along with the orbit script. I must have missed the change, because all the javascript files are in the new folder. I must have been quite tired. Thanks again!

Comment: So my answer solved your issue but neither did you accept it nor upvote it?

Comment: It was the right direction, but you strayed from the docs. While your example  implementation did promote best practices (use of a CDN), I was trying to find why it didn't work based on the code at the foundation docs. Your answer is probably better than their code, but I didn't know that then. So I gave you an upvote but I didn't give you the answer. If I had known your code was better and why when I closed this, you would have gotten the answer and an upvote . Have an good week and thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have failed to carefully follow the [Javascript Installation section](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html) of Foundation documentation.

You missed at least two steps:

- require jQuery;
- initialize Foundation.

Also, the code you provided in the question is different from the code you have on the actual page. On the page you use `<ul class= "data-orbit">` while the correct code is `<ul data-orbit>`.

Here's a demo of everything set up properly: http://jsbin.com/ixuluw/3/edit

Comment: It does make it work. I thought this: <script>
        document.write('<script src=`javascripts/vendor/'
            + ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery')
            + '.js><\/script>')</script> loaded either zepto or jquery. In addition, I seem to imply that the foundation.min.css was not available in the compass/sass version of foundation 4. Am I wrong?